SwiftUI cannot multiline a popover
Is it possible to have a .popover on macOS with multiline text?
Button("Popover me") {
    showing.toggle()
}
.popover(isPresented: $showing) {
    Text("This is a long text that should be a multiline text")
        .lineLimit(nil) // Just to try, but it's not changing anything
        .frame(maxWidth: 100)
        .padding()
}


Also tried using .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true), but it takes too much and does not hug content


Add a frame modifier where the max width is set tot infinity to the Text
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

And then wrap the Text in a Group where you set your width and height requirements for the popover
Group {
    Text("This is a long text that should be a multiline text")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
}
.frame(width: 100, height: .infinity)


The width is the issue here. I'm trying to 'constraint' the width to a given size and let the hight be dynamic. I want (as in the example) to have .frame(maxWidth: 100). The default behavior is in fact, to let the width extend.

Interesting. So I've narrowed it down to maxWidth. In my original code, if I only change .frame(maxWidth: 100) to .frame(width: 100), I get a nice multiline. The issue is with maxWidth.
